# Open a web folder (Sharepoint 2007)through openFileDialog

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, openfiledialog

I have the following snippet of code written in C#:

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\\\fwm-storage\\users\\" + 
curUser + "\\My Documents\\My Pictures";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Images (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
// blah, blah, blah
```

Which works great and all, but, I want to be able to add/change the ability to have the **openFileDialog.InitialDirectory** be a web folder on our SharePoint server.  Say, for example: "http:\intranet\company\division\photos"

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can do this.  I have exhausted my morning looking for an answer and my GoogleFu is apparently not up to par.  I have seen sparse recommendations, but, it looks like it might require WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) or installing a Sharepoint SDK for Visual Studio (which might(?) allow me to directly access the SharePoint dBase).  I am not above installing the SDK if that will get me to where I need to go; but not so much on the WPF.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Even if just to say it can't be done.  If you need more information, always happy to oblige.

Thanks.

Jasooomian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharepoint can usually be accessed using UNC paths just as above. IE

\\mysharepointserver.domain.tld\path\to\my\document\library\