# wpf sharepoint 2010 file picker

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint-2010

Is there any free control available like openfiledialog in winforms that allows you to pick files from sharepoint 2010? I have sharepoint 2010 foundation installed in a Windows 2008 R2 server. I want to allow users to browse and select files from a Wpf app. It is possible to write something like this using client object model. Just want to know if someone has already created a control like this already so that I don't reinvent the wheel.

In case there isn't any can anyone please give me some directions on how to create one with treeview structure on left like openfile dialog?

Edit: Added C# Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't just use the standard windows open file dialog?

example in vb.net

```
Dim dialog As New Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
Dim result = dialog.ShowDialog
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505257/open-a-web-folder-sharepoint-2007through-openfiledialog)  might be helpful

Comment: Thanks Dave. Will give it a try at work tomorrow and post the results

Comment: It works in Windows 7 and windows 2008 R2. However it does not work in Windows 2003. The part that does not work is mapping a sharepoint folder as UNC. a "net use"command in windows 2003 returns a "System error 67. Network name not found" error. According to this [link](http://devwfb.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/how-to-map-https-only-web-folder-to.html) ports other than 80 wold not work in 2003. I'm not using https but using port 8195 as there's another website using 80.  This is for anyone reading this question and in same situation as me .