# Select large file path from Web using OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, sharepoint, openfiledialog

I am trying to select a file from a SharePoint site using OpenFileDialog, with the SharePoint uri formatted similar to [Open a web folder (Sharepoint 2007)through openFileDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505257/open-a-web-folder-sharepoint-2007through-openfiledialog).

When I try to select a file greater than 50Mb, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h2bu.jpg). It looks like it is due to a windows registry setting related to WebClient\Parameters\FileSizeLimitInBytes. However, I don't have rights to change this setting.

I can download the file using WebRequest when I use a string literal of the uri, but I need a way to navigate and select a file path string.

Is there an alterative way to select a file from a SharePoint library?

```
private void button_File_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fdb = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdb.Filter = "Access DBs Or Zips|*.accdb;*.zip";
        fdb.FilterIndex = 1;
        fdb.ShowHelp = true;

        fdb.InitialDirectory = SharePointPath;

        if (fdb.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            textBox_File.Text = fdb.FileName;

        fdb = null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

`fdb.ValidateNames = false;`

I couldn't test your explicit example. I disallowed permissions on a file which wouldn't let me click `Open`, it would show an error that I could only hit `OK` on like your example. But setting the above ValidateNames to false allowed me to hit `Open` and show the filename even though I don't have rights to access the file itself.